# C#. Ошибка: Не удается открыть банк макросов

Tags: c#, ms-word

Выходит ошибка при открытии вордовского документа из программы на C#:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A175D): Не удается открыть банк макросов.
```

Как решить проблему?

Я пробовала запускать под правами администратора, пробовала переустановить ворд 2010 - не помогло.

```
        Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
        Word._Document wordDocument = null;
        wordApplication.Visible = true;

        var templatePathObj = @"D:\report.docx";

        try
        {
            wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(templatePathObj);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (wordDocument != null)
            {
                wordDocument.Close(false);
                wordDocument = null;
            }
            wordApplication.Quit();
            wordApplication = null;
            throw;
        }

        //{date_now}
        Word.Range wRdn = wordApplication.Selection.Range;
        wRdn.Find.Execute(FindText: "{date_now}", ReplaceWith: dn);
```

Comment: Без примера кода глухой номер...

Comment: @Fox добавила. у меня на 2007 работает, а на 2010 ошибка

Comment: добавьте в проект на 2010 namespace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word через "Add Reference" он вам должен будет переписать вот так:             _Application wordApplication = new Application();
            _Document wordDocument = null;

Comment: @Fox студии нет на том компьютере и установить нет возможности...

Comment: @Fox, у меня студия 2015, а ворд 2007 - работает. А на другом компьютере студии нет, а  ворд 2010 установлен, там ошибка.

Comment: COM объекты у разных версий MS Office свои, поэтому вы не сможете проект созданный для MS Office 2007 применить к MS Office 2010. Вам придется переписать проект для каждой версии MS Office. Я с этим уже сталкивался.

Comment: @Fox просто сейчас я использую using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; вроде тоже самое...Попробую поставить офис 2010

Comment: @Fox, я поставила 2010, добавила Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library в проект, но ошибка "Не удаётся открыть банк макросов" так и осталась. Есть ещё какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Я один раз столкнулся со схожей проблемой, поэтому задам наводящий вопрос. А в "Центре управления безопасностью" Word-а в разделе "Параметры макросов" установлено разрешение на "Предоставлять доступ к объектной модели проектов VBA"?

Comment: у вас получилось решить эту проблему?

Comment: @yuriybolotin99, да, написала в ответе к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Я удалила word, перезагрузила компьютер, установила заново word. Проблема исчезла. Дописала программу и отдала exe-файл коллегам.
2. Далее такая же ошибка начала появляться и у коллег... Оказалось, проблема была в том, что они перетаскивали exe-файл приложения из архива, а не распаковывали архив.